# Huggingface dataset map saves list as numpy array instead of as a list

Tags: numpy, huggingface-datasets

I have been trying to have a function that ouputs a list to map it to my dataset. However, when trying to pass the output to a csv or a DataFrame, it appears as a Numpy array instead of as a list.

if I have the following function:

```
def fetch_embedding(data):
    text = data["text"]
    out = trainer.predict(text)
    embeddings = out[0][1][-1][:,0,:]
    embeddings = embeddings.tolist()
    return {"embeddings" : embeddings}
```

So, I’m very intentionally passing the torch tensor to a list. Then I map it to the dataset to save these embeddings:

```
dataset = dataset.map(fetch_embedding)
```

We check whether the dataset stored the list as an actual list:

```
df = datset.to_pandas()
A = df.iloc[0].loc["embeddings"]
print(type(A))
```

The output of this is the following:

```
<class ‘numpy.ndarray’>
```

Is there any way to actually have the output of the map saved as a list instead of it being passed as a Numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from lhoestq at the huggingface forums [[link]](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/dataset-map-saves-list-as-numpy-array-instead-of-as-list/28823/2):

> Hi ! This behavior comes from Arrow:

```
>>> df.iloc[0].loc["embeddings"]
array([0, 1, 2])
```

> Arrow uses numpy arrays to enable fast zero-copy conversions from Arrow to pandas. Converting to a python list requires to copy the data into new pythons objects, which can be costly in some cases.

> You can get a python list using

```
>>> df["embeddings"] = [arr.tolist() for arr in df["embeddings"]]
```